# URL inside of another URL (as path)

Tags: java, rest, url, restlet

I want to use the following type of URL in Restlet: `http://url.com/http://www.anotherurl.com/path`
As a result I want to get `http://www.anotherurl.com/path` as a parameter.
However it does nothing.

Also, if I use `http://url.com/path` , then I receive "path" without problems. `http://url.com/www.anotherurl.com` gives me `www.anotherurl.com`. However `http://url.com/www.anotherurl.com/path` is 404.

Answer (score 4):

You need to encode the parameter special characters properly. Use [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to do so.

Comment: Are you talking about the server or client side? If server, I do not understand what I should do and most importantly why..

Comment: Client side. On server you have to get your path part of URL and similarly decode using URLDecoder.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there are two parts here.

- The URL building using the `Reference` class:

  ```
  Reference ref = new Reference();
  ref.setScheme("http");
  ref.setHostDomain("localhost");
  ref.setHostPort(8182);
  ref.addSegment("test");
  ref.addSegment("http://test");

  ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(ref);
  cr.get();
  ```
- Getting the value as a path parameter and decode it. Here is the routing configuration in the application class:

  ```
  public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
      Router router = new Router(getContext());
      router.attach("/test/{id}", MyServerResource.class);
      return router;
  }
  ```

  And the corresponding code in the server resource:

  ```
  public class MyServerResource extends ServerResource {
      @Get
      public Representation get() {
          String id = getAttribute("id");
          // Prints http%3A%2F%2Ftest
          System.out.println("id = "+id);
          // Prints http://test
          System.out.println("id = "+Reference.decode(id));
          return new EmptyRepresentation();
      }
  }
  ```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: It does not helped, 404 error. Here is the log (I run on Apache Tomcat):
`Dec 02, 2015 4:38:24 AM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
INFO: 2015-12-02 04:38:24 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.1 8080 GET /test/http://www.com - 404 439 0 20 http://localhost:8080 curl/7.35.0 -`
But without http:// works fine:
`id = www.com
id = www.com
Dec 02, 2015 4:36:52 AM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
INFO: 2015-12-02 04:36:52 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.1 8080 GET /test/www.com - 204 0 0 89 http://localhost:8080 curl/7.35.0 -`

Comment: Hi. I'm really surprised since I made it work with version 2.3.1. I just commited my project in a github repo (https://github.com/templth/restlet-stackoverflow/tree/master/restlet/test-url-encoding) so you can make a try...